# Resize a BorderContainer onClick

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo, resize

I'm trying to finish up my app and am having some HTML/CSS issues when I try to resize a bordercontainer to allow for a hidden div to show on click of a search button

Below is a simple illustration of my app on initial load:
[image]

This is how I would like the app to look after the search button is clicked:

[image]

Previously I had used the following code to resize the center pane:

```
dojo.style(dijit.byId("map"), "height", "83%");
```

This no longer works.

My HTML is:

```
    </script> 
  </head>
  <body class="claro"> 
    <div dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="headline" gutters="false" style="width:100%;height:55px;margin:0;">
<!--Header Logo-->
                <div id="headerlogo" 
                            < a href="http://www.marioncountyfl.org/InformationSystems/IS_GIS.aspx"><img src="images/map1.png" alt="View Logo" /></a> 
                </div>
<!--Header-->
                    <header>Zoning Classifications</header> <div style="position:absolute; right:160px; top:10px;  z-Index:99;"></div>
        </div>
<!--Help Button-->
                <div id="help" title="Help";> 
                            <a href="help.html"><img src="images/Help1.png" alt="Help" style="border:none" /></a> 
                </div>
<!--Basemap Gallery-->      
                <div id="subheader" style="position:absolute; right:60px; top:10px; z-Index:98;">
                            <div id="basemapbutton">
                                        <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" baseClass="tomButton" title="Switch Basemap">    
                                                <img src="images/imgBaseMap.png"/>     
                                                        <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick">   
                                                            toggler[(dojo.style("basemaptoggle","display") == "none") ? 'show':'hide']();
                                                        </script>
                                        </button>   
                                                    <div id="basemaptoggle" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" style="#900;display: none;">
                                                        <div id="basemapGallery">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                            </div>
<!--Search-->
                    <div id="search" >
                            Parcel ID: <input type="text" id="parcel" size="20" value="4209-111-074" />
                                        <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button"  data-dojo-props='onClick:function(){ doFind();}, value:"Search"'">
                                            Search
                                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
<!--TOC-->
        <div id="content" dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="headline" gutters="true" style="width: 100%; height: 95%;">
                            <div dojotype="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="leftPane" region="left" splitter="true">
                                    <div id="tocDiv">
                                    </div>         
                            </div>
<!--Map-->
                        <div id="map" dojotype="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" region="center" style="height:100%; doLayout:'false'">
                                <div class="watermark">
                                        <a href="http://www.marioncountyfl.org/InformationSystems/IS_GIS.aspx"><img src="images/MCLogo.png" alt="View Logo" style="border:none" /></a>
                                </div>  
                                <!--Data Grid-->
                                <div id ="datagrid" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane"  splitter="true" region="bottom" style="width:100%; height:125px;">
                                        <table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid" data-dojo-id="grid"  id="grid" data-dojo-props="rowsPerPage:'5', rowSelector:'20px'">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th field="Parcel Identification Number" width="10%">
                            Parcel ID
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th field="Assessing Neighbornood Code" width ="20%">
                            Neighborhood Code
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th field="Property Class Code" width="10%">
                            Property Class
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th field="Site Address" width="57%">
                            Address
                                                    </th>
                                                    <th field" width="2%"> <div class="GridCloseIcon" title="Close Grid" onclick="esri.hide(datagrid)"></div>
                                                    </th>                   
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                        </table>
                                </div>
                        </div>
        </div>
<!--Splash Screen-->
            <div id="dialogLoadMessage" dojotype="dijit.Dialog" style="width: 350px;">
            <table>
                <tr>
                   <td>
                      <div id="divLoadMessage" style="text-align:center">
                      </div>
                   </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td align="center">
                      <div class="divOk" onclick="dijit.byId('dialogLoadMessage').hide();">
                                                OK
                                            </div>
                   </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
      </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add or remove *datagrid* `ContentPane` via calling `addChild()` and `removeChild()` on its parent *content* `BorderContainer`.

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/7WRSh/

Comment: This looks good. Possibly a N00b question, but I have a search function where I have placed the `esri.show(datagrid);` code so that it shows on click of the search button. How can I link the search and the show, given the fiddle you posted?

Comment: I would recommend to invoke directly functions to `addChild` and `removeChild`, but if you can't you can use [`dojo/aspect::around`](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/aspect#around). I updated the aforementioned jsFiddle to explain how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you add, and  toggle the padding of the bottom grid— using `box-sizing: border-box`— instead of resizing the center pane. Use `js` to add and remove the padding, which should reflect the height of the `bottom grid` when it's active and probably `0px` when it's unactive. If the center pane content has a `postion: absolute` and `height: 100%` it should make scaling easy. I've used the method extensively to great affect on large scale applications, it's also cross browser compatible, but if you need to support legacy versions of IE make sure to use a `box-sizing:border-box` polyfill ton enforce the box model.

For more info on `box-sizing` http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/